# How to store all array value to one array?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Title is a bit 'misleading, basically I'm trying to replicate an array like this:

```
'columns': [
    { id: 1, name: 'Operator1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Operator2' }
]
```

in one variable:

```
var myMap = {id: ['0', '1'], name:['Operator1', 'Operator2']}
alert(myMap.id[0]);
```

The problem's that `columns` doesn't get the value of `myMap`, maybe I'm wrong with the array struct? See this code:

Essentially the result that's a I want achieve is this:

```
'multiColAgendaWeek': {
    'type': 'multiColAgenda',
    'duration': { weeks: 1 },
    'columns': myMap
}
```

If instead I pass `myMap` like `myMap.id` or `myMap.Name` I get:

> undefined

on my fullcalendar.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I'm using this class extension: https://github.com/mherrmann/fullcalendar-columns/

**Image explain:**

[image]

If I use the myMap array as `columns: myMap`

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. What you have in the first code block is not what the value in `myMap` represents.

Comment: I've posted an image for explain better. The column rapresent the resource of the calendar. See the image.

Comment: The problem is the fact if the calendar expects `[{ id: 1, name: 'Operator1' }]`, that is not what you are giving it.

Comment: Yeah, there's a way to fix this?

Comment: Put it in that format... Is there a reason you have it the way you do? Either loop through and build the new Array, or change whatever is building it in the first place.

Comment: Practically the array will be enhanced by data in a database, thus loading the operators from the database. While in the first code I posted gil operators are defined internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple map function to convert it.

```js
var myMap = {id: ['0', '1'], name:['Operator1', 'Operator2']};

var updated = myMap.id.map(function (val, ind) {
  return { "id" : val, "name" : myMap.name[ind] };
});

console.log(updated);
```

Still would be better to do it on wherever the data is being generated.